Installing a whole house water filter
Last time our plumber came he said it would be easy to install a whole house water filter system ourselves. I'm no plumbing expert but still doing quite a bit around the house ourselves. We're not against having him come install it either. This is where he said we should be installing it:

I assume to install one I close the middle valve, install the filter and then open both bottom valves? How risky is it to do this myself?

Looks like the place for a whole house filter/water softener. I assume it's inline before the HW heater. Just do your research and follow the manufacturers directions.

If the long pipe on the right is your main feed to the house, then you are right. The lower right valve would be your filter in, the lower left valve would be your filter out. Both would normally be opened. The upper middle valve would be your filter bypass valve and would normally be closed.
It would not be risky to do yourself. It looks like you already have the threads on the pipes so you wouldn't have to do any sweating. Just remember to install unions on both pipes.
